# Load RSA public key file and convert to a binary array in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rsa

I have a text file in PEM format for an RSA private key, for example:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAhlxsnlo31l3u3w5jWyYpGVaNi9eDslPHgNV+I8Jb0hxGKXka
hnVOBu+b5IrcPcivWBIPQBNJp2svD/GVFWZQsKXshZA3meiRO+/k3qjBh7aDaakW
...etc
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I load this in with the Python RSA library:

```
import rsa

with open('somefile.pem', mode='rb') as privatefile:
    keydata = privatefile.read()
privkey = rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(keydata)
print(type(privkey))
print(privkey)
```

This outputs five decimal numbers in brackets, like:

```
<class 'rsa.key.PrivateKey'>
PrivateKey(1234..., 7889..., etc)
```

How do I convert these numbers or class to a "binary array" (this is to pass the key to an API) ?

**Update**
I'm guessing that "binary" is DER format?

Reference: https://stuvel.eu/python-rsa-doc/reference.html#classes

Comment: Unfortunately there is no single standard format for RSA private keys, you will have to check the API to see what they specifically want. The package you are using seems to like PKCS#1 private key format, and you can get that simply by called `priv_key.save_pkcs1('DER')`, as you have surmised DER is the binary format. A more commonly accepted format for private keys is PKCS#8, so be aware in case your API doesn't seem to accept your key. This format is not supported by Python RSA, see [this](https://stuvel.eu/python-rsa-doc/compatibility.html#interoperability-with-pkcs-8) discussion.

Answer (score 2):

The text representation of an `rsa.PrivateKey` object is generating [here](https://github.com/sybrenstuvel/python-rsa/blob/master/rsa/key.py#L384), like this:

```
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return 'PrivateKey(%i, %i, %i, %i, %i)' % (self.n, self.e, self.d, self.p, self.q)
```

So if you want an array of those values, you can just write:

```
privkey = rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(keydata)
privkey_array = [privkey.n, privkey.e, privkey.d, privkey.p, privkey.q]
```